# Global variable update AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, post, navigator

Below is my full JS file beginning to end. I set a variable 'rendered' outside all functions. Then, since it is required in the if check just before issuing a POST request I want to use it as flag and update it's value to be true upon post request completion. The issue is that all the console.log calls do print the changed value but it does not persist. When again the position coordinates are fetched automatically in the watchPosition function, calculateDistance function is invoked again. Then, the previous saved value with "window.rendered = true" is not there, it is actually false and it enters the if condition. How can I achieve the goal of not issuing the post request again until another post request changes this flag variable back to false?

```
var rendered = false;
    
    function myfunc() {
        rendered = true;
        console.log(window.rendered);
    }
    
    function updatePosition() {
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(calculateDistance);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.")
        }
    }
    
    function calculateDistance(position) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var target = new google.maps.LatLng(55.85365783555865, -4.288739944549508);
        var dis = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pos, target);
        console.log(window.rendered);
        var self = this;
        if(dis <= 1000 && dis >= 0 && window.rendered == false) {
            console.log("Distance"+dis);
            var url = '/dogpark/near_park/';
            var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                    in_proximity : 1
                },
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    myfunc();
                    self.rendered = true;
                    window.rendered = true;
                    alert(window.rendered);
                    window.location = '/dogpark/near_park/';
                },
                complete: function(data) {
                    console.log("Trying");
                    window.rendered = true;
                    alert(window.rendered);
                },
                error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                    console.log(xhr.status+": "+xhr.responseText);
                },
                
            });
        }
    
    window.onload = updatePosition()
```

Comment: The issue could be that the network call is not synchronous. `calculateDistance` is being called before it finishes and that can happen over and over again.

Comment: How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use another variable to track the ajax call completion. So that you don't make another Ajax call until the previous one returns a repsonse(success/failure).

```
var isWaitingForResponse = false;
...
function calculateDistance(position) {
  ...
  if(dis <= 1000 && dis >= 0 && window.rendered == false && !isWaitingForResponse) {
    isWaitingForResponse = true;
    ...
      success: function(data) {
        isWaitingForResponse = false
        ...
      },
      complete: function(data) {
        isWaitingForResponse = false
        ...
      },
      error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
        isWaitingForResponse = false
        ...
      }
...
```